# Read 4 spinner item to another 4 spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

Can someone help me to check what's wrong with my code ? I have 4 `spinner` in `WorkDetails` which named `spinner1,2,3 and 4` and their value has been inserted to `SQLite`.Now I want to display the item selected in `spinner1,2,3,4` in the `project1,project2,project3,project4` spinner but failed to do so.

I have checked every single step but still cannot figuring out the problem.

**Update.java**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.updatepage);
            final String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1");
            final String date=getIntent().getExtras().getString("date1");
            final String ID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            RetrievePage(name,date,ID);
        }

         public void addProject1(String c)
            {
                project1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
                String[] arr = new String[]{"Pro-XXX-XXX","TRN-XXX-XXX","SRV-XXX-XXX","PRO-REE-BERGARDING","PRO-SKM-SSS","PRO-SKM-DI","PRO-SKM-PACKING","PRO-SIE-AVAGO_S110",
                "PRO-SIE-BIOCON","PRO-BCM-T13/T17","TRIN-IN_HOUSE","TRIN-EXTERNAL","SRIV-SIE-LEMONGRASS","SRV-PW-SIMOCODE","SRV-REE-SIMOCODE","PRO-SKM-D5","PRO-SKM-DRIOU","PRO-BKI-DESMET",
                "PRO-BKI-INFINEON","PRO-INH-ANDROID","PRO-BCM-S120","PRO-GAW-OP"};
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                String project11 = c;
                list.add(project11);
                for(String s:arr){
                    if(!list.contains(s)){
                        list.add(s);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                project1.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            public void addProject2(String d)
            {
                project2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner9);
                String[] arr = new String[]{"Pro-XXX-XXX","TRN-XXX-XXX","SRV-XXX-XXX","PRO-REE-BERGARDING","PRO-SKM-SSS","PRO-SKM-DI","PRO-SKM-PACKING","PRO-SIE-AVAGO_S110",
                        "PRO-SIE-BIOCON","PRO-BCM-T13/T17","TRIN-IN_HOUSE","TRIN-EXTERNAL","SRIV-SIE-LEMONGRASS","SRV-PW-SIMOCODE","SRV-REE-SIMOCODE","PRO-SKM-D5","PRO-SKM-DRIOU","PRO-BKI-DESMET",
                        "PRO-BKI-INFINEON","PRO-INH-ANDROID","PRO-BCM-S120","PRO-GAW-OP"};
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                String project22 = d;
                list.add(project22);
                for(String s:arr){
                    if(!list.contains(s)){
                        list.add(s);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                project2.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            public void addProject3(String e)
            {
                project3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner13);
                String[] arr = new String[]{"Pro-XXX-XXX","TRN-XXX-XXX","SRV-XXX-XXX","PRO-REE-BERGARDING","PRO-SKM-SSS","PRO-SKM-DI","PRO-SKM-PACKING","PRO-SIE-AVAGO_S110",
                        "PRO-SIE-BIOCON","PRO-BCM-T13/T17","TRIN-IN_HOUSE","TRIN-EXTERNAL","SRIV-SIE-LEMONGRASS","SRV-PW-SIMOCODE","SRV-REE-SIMOCODE","PRO-SKM-D5","PRO-SKM-DRIOU","PRO-BKI-DESMET",
                        "PRO-BKI-INFINEON","PRO-INH-ANDROID","PRO-BCM-S120","PRO-GAW-OP"};
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                String project33 = e;
                list.add(project33);
                for(String s:arr){
                    if(!list.contains(s)){
                        list.add(s);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                project3.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            public void addProject4(String f)
            {
                project4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner14);
                String[] arr = new String[]{"Pro-XXX-XXX","TRN-XXX-XXX","SRV-XXX-XXX","PRO-REE-BERGARDING","PRO-SKM-SSS","PRO-SKM-DI","PRO-SKM-PACKING","PRO-SIE-AVAGO_S110",
                        "PRO-SIE-BIOCON","PRO-BCM-T13/T17","TRIN-IN_HOUSE","TRIN-EXTERNAL","SRIV-SIE-LEMONGRASS","SRV-PW-SIMOCODE","SRV-REE-SIMOCODE","PRO-SKM-D5","PRO-SKM-DRIOU","PRO-BKI-DESMET",
                        "PRO-BKI-INFINEON","PRO-INH-ANDROID","PRO-BCM-S120","PRO-GAW-OP"};
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                String project44 = f;
                list.add(project44);
                for(String s:arr){
                    if(!list.contains(s)){
                        list.add(s);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                project4.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


            public void RetrievePage(String name,String date, String id) {
                final String name2 = name;
                final String date2=date;
                final String id2 = id;
                final EditText name3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
                final EditText date3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);

                final EditText per1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText20);
                final EditText per2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText24);
                final EditText per3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText28);
                final EditText per4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText32);

                database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                c = database.rawQuery("SELECT i.Weather, i.Status,w.Subcontractors, w.NumberOfPerson, w.NumberOfHours, wd.Project, wd.WorkDescription, wd.Per, wd.TimeIn, wd.TimeOut FROM Information i LEFT JOIN WorkForce w ON w.TInfo_id = i._id LEFT JOIN WorkDetails wd ON wd.Twf_id=w._id WHERE i.Name = ? AND i._id= ? ",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(name2),String.valueOf(id2)}, null);

                    if (c != null) {
                        while (c.moveToNext()) {

                      Details WD = new Details();


                       String Weather = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather));

                               String Project11=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
                               String Project22=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
                               String 

Project33=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
                            String Project44=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Project));
                            String Per1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Per));
                            String Per2=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Per));
                            String Per3=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Per));
                            String Per4=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Per));
                            addProject1(Project11);
                            addProject2(Project22);
                            addProject3(Project33);
                           addProject4(Project44);
                           addWeather(Weather);

                            WD.setProject(Project11);
                            WD.setProject(Project22);
                            WD.setProject(Project33);
                            WD.setProject(Project44);
                            WD.setPer(Per1);
                            WD.setPer(Per2);
                            WD.setPer(Per3);
                            WD.setPer(Per4);
                            per1.setText(Per1);
                            per2.setText(Per2);
                            per3.setText(Per3);
                            per4.setText(Per4);

                        }

                    }
                    c.close();


                }
```

**Error LogCat**

```
  Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 2364
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:580)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:410)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:5922)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildren(ViewGroup.java:5899)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.onMeasure(AbsoluteLayout.java:66)
```

I have one activity which has one spinner and the code below works fine to me.

```
public void addWeather(String a) {
    weather3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
    String[] arr = new String[]{"Sunny","Cloudy","Rainy","Thunderstorm"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String weather = a;
    list.add(weather);
    for(String s:arr){
        if(!list.contains(s)){
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdatePage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    weather3.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Are you explicitly or implicitly passing null as the argument to one of your addProjectX() methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception seems to happen outside of your code (but is somewhat related to your code), you may want to put breakpoints at the start of each of your methods and see where your app crashes exactly to help shed light on the issue. Alternatively, put log prints at the start and end of each of your methods to see which method starts and fails to end and help to detect where the problem is.

My guess is you're passing null as an argument to one of your addProject() methods which causes the list to contain a null object, and then when the adapter attempts to call the toString() method on that null object, you get the error. This object could be passed implicitly as well, for example, as a variable that you forgot to initialize. What you can do is check if the argument is null and only if it isn't, add it to the list, or exit the method on its start if the argument is null or implement whatever logic you want.

Comment: BTW: Your code is kinda messy, which may open the door for future bugs and make it difficult to maintain your application. Instead of having 4 methods, one for each spinner, you should have a single method that takes the desired spinner as an extra argument, thus reduce code duplication. The static strings that you define inside the body of each method and always add can be defined in strings.xml file and obtained from there, or better - added to the spinner inside the layout file and then you can just add and remove more items as needed. I hope it's clear.

Comment: It crashed even though I use addProject1() methods only and delete the others three function